# Gnuplot-Plotting only colorbox

Tags: gnuplot, colorbox

I am plotting several heatmaps using `Gnuplot`. However, I am not not using group plot in `Gnuplot` as I have decided to do this better in `Latex` with individual heatmaps obtained. What I need now from `Gnuplot` is a plot/figure with only `colorbox` (nothing but `colorbox`). Is there any way to do it in Gnuplot?

Comment: So you want to plot N heat map without colorbox and one colorbox (without heat map)?

Comment: @TomSolid: exactly

Comment: Take a look at these examples (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html) of defining palette. Sure, you have to know the absolute minima and maxima of the heatmaps.

Answer (score 3):

Eg. if your heatmaps are from 5-12:

```
unset key
set view map
set style data pm3d
set style function pm3d
set xtics  norangelimit 1
unset ytics
unset ztics
set title "Colorbox for heatmaps" 
set xrange [ 5.0000 : 12.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
unset colorbox
splot (x-5)/(12-5)
```

[image]

OR if you want it to be vertical:

```
set size ratio 3
unset key
set view map
set style data pm3d
set style function pm3d
unset xtics
set ytics norangelimit 1
unset ztics
set title "Colorbox for heatmaps" 
set yrange [ 5.0000 : 12.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
unset colorbox
splot (y-5)/(12-5)
```

[image]